# How to move cursor from one text field to another automatically in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    scrlView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y-70), animated: true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    scrlView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)

    return true
}
```

How can I move cursor from one textfield to another automatically after entering value in the first textfield?

Comment: How do you know if user finished to enter the value in the field?

Comment: Yes. I have the same question too..

Answer (score 2):

first, you need add tags to your text fields orderly

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        let nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
        // Try to find next responder
        var nextResponderTxt: UITextField!
        nextResponderTxt = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag) as? UITextField
        if ((nextResponderTxt) != nil) {
            // Found next responder, so set it.
            nextResponderTxt.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            // Not found, so remove keyboard.
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return false; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
    }
```

Also you can change the return key to next

[image]

Comment: How do you know if user finished to enter the value in the field?

Comment: @RakeshMohan It can be detected by means of delegated when a key is pressed, when I finish keystroke.

`textFieldDidBeginEditing`
`textFieldDidEndEditing`

or with `Value Changed` Event

Comment: Can you explain it with code? Since I am new to ios I am facing difficulty in understanding the code..

Comment: let length = textField.text!.utf16.count + string.utf16.count - range.length
        
        return length <= 1.

Comment: I have added the above code in should character change in delegate method to limit the character to 1